# Flex DateField SelectedField Always Set to NULL

Tags: apache-flex, datefield

I'd like to format the DateField string as "MM/YYYY". However, I notice that its selectedDate property is always set to null even if a valid date is selected. Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks,

```
<mx:FormItem label="Start Date" required="true">
    <mx:DateField id="startDateField" formatString="MM-YYYY"/>
</mx:FormItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the parseFunction property on your dateField.

```
<mx:DateField id="startDateField" formatString="MM-YYYY" parseFunction="{null}" />
```

I think the formatString is messing up with the selectedDate value on the dateField.

Check [here](http://www.cubicleman.com/2008/02/12/flex-datefield-and-formats/) for much deeper explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer Angelo. Flex is really weird at times!